# Jacobian and Stokes Theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

Let $f:U \to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ a $C^{2}$ function in the open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Suppose $D \subset U$ is a compact domain with boundary $\partial D$ of $C^{2}$ class. If $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in \partial D$, prove that $\int_{D} det f'(x)dx=0$.

I know to prove only the bidimensional case...

Comment: As Green's and Stokes' theorems are very close, your $2D$ proof should work also in the higher dimensional case... or do you use something specific about being in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: I  used the 1-form $\omega = fg_{x}dx+ fg_{y}dy$ and applied the Stokes theorem $\int_{D} d\omega = \int_{\partial D} \omega$. Where $F=(f,g)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly,
$$
\det f' \, dx_1 \wedge \dots \wedge dx_n = f^*(dx_1 \wedge \dots \wedge dx_n) = d f^*(x_1) \wedge \dots \wedge d f^*(x_n) = d(f_1 \wedge df_2 \wedge \dots \wedge df_n).
$$

By Stoke's theorem,
$$
\int_D \det f'(x) \, dx = \int_{\partial D} f_1 \, df_2 \wedge \dots \wedge df_n = 0
$$
since $f_1 = 0$ on $\partial D$.